# Finding intersection of a row and column using listboxes in a userform in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have multiple excel worksheets within the same workbook that are formatted the same. In each of these worksheets I have dates from a2:a416 and I have numbers as headers at b1,d1,f1,h1,j1,l1,n1,p1,r1,t1,v1, and x1. In a user form I have two listboxes, one containing the dates titled ListBoxRows and one containing the numbers titled ListBoxColumns. I'm trying to write VBA code that after I press a button it takes the value from the ListBoxRows ListBox and selects the matching row, then takes the value from ListBoxHeaders and selects the matching column, then selects the cell where both that row and column intersect. For example, if the date 11/29/23 is in cell a18 and the number 0.00814 is the header for column D, I need it to ultimately select cell d18.

```
Sub FindColumn()
Dim selectedValue As String
Dim headerRange As Range
Dim headerCell As Range
Dim targetColumn As Long

    ' Get the selected value from the list box
    selectedValue = ListBoxHeaders.Value
    
    ' Set the range of headers (assuming headers are in the first row)
    Set headerRange = activeSheet.Rows(1)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the header range
    For Each headerCell In headerRange
        ' Check if the header matches the selected value
        If headerCell.Value = selectedValue Then 'error on this line
            ' Get the column number of the matching header
            targetColumn = headerCell.Column
            ' Exit the loop since we found the match
            Exit For
        End If
    Next headerCell
    
    ' Display the column number
    MsgBox "The column number for " & selectedValue & " is: " & targetColumn

End Sub
```

I wanted to start off with just selecting the column to get my feet wet but it is not working. It gives an error code of type mismatch at the bolded line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `For Each headerCell In headerRange.Cells` instead.

Comment: How did you insert the values in `ListBoxHeaders`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Application.Match` is simpler when you want an exact match:

```
Sub FindColumn()
    Dim selectedValue As String, m As Variant

    selectedValue = ListBoxHeaders.Value
    Debug.Print "Selected:", selectedValue
    
    m = Application.Match(selectedValue, ActiveSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then 'got a match (`m` will be an error if not match)
        MsgBox "The column number for '" & selectedValue & "' is: " & targetColumn
    Else
        MsgBox "No match for '" & selectedValue & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```